# Select one record from two tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

There are three tables:

1. A table about students: `s41071030(sno, sname, ssex, sage, sdept)`
2. A table about course: `c41071030(cno, cname, cpno, credit)`
3. A table about selecting courses: `sc41071030(sno, cno, grade)`

Now, I want select the details about a student whose `sdept='CS'` and he or she has selected the most courses in department `'CS'`.

Comment: JOINs and aggregate functions(these are terms you should google) will do the trick.

Comment: +1 for including table names and schemas in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As with any modestly complex SQL statement, it is best to do 'TDQD' — Test Driven Query Design.  Start off with simple parts of the question and build them into a more complex answer.

To find out how many courses each student in the CS department is taking, we write:

```
SELECT S.Sno, COUNT(*) NumCourses
  FROM s41071030 S
  JOIN sc41071030 SC ON S.Sno = SC.Sno
 WHERE S.Sdept = 'CS'
 GROUP BY S.Sno;
```

We now need to find the largest value of NumCourses:

```
SELECT MAX(NumCourses) MaxCourses
  FROM (SELECT S.Sno, COUNT(*) NumCourses
          FROM s41071030 S
          JOIN sc41071030 SC ON S.Sno = SC.Sno
         WHERE S.Sdept = 'CS'
         GROUP BY S.Sno
       )
```

Now we need to join that result with the sub-query, so it is time for a CTE (Common Table Expression):

```
WITH N AS
    (SELECT S.Sno, COUNT(*) NumCourses
       FROM s41071030 S
       JOIN sc41071030 SC ON S.Sno = SC.Sno
      WHERE S.Sdept = 'CS'
      GROUP BY S.Sno
    )
SELECT N.Sno
  FROM N
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(NumCourses) MaxCourses FROM N) M
    ON M.MaxCourses = N.NumCourses;
```

And we need to get the student details, so we join that with the student table:

```
WITH N AS
    (SELECT S.Sno, COUNT(*) NumCourses
       FROM s41071030 S
       JOIN sc41071030 SC ON S.Sno = SC.Sno
      WHERE S.Sdept = 'CS'
      GROUP BY S.Sno
    )
SELECT S.*
  FROM s41071030 S
  JOIN N ON N.Sno = S.Sno
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(NumCourses) MaxCourses FROM N) M
    ON M.MaxCourses = N.NumCourses;
```

Lightly tested SQL: you were warned.  To test, run the component queries, making sure you get reasonable results each time.  Don't move on to the next query until the previous one is working correctly.

Note that the courses table turns out to be immaterial to the query you are solving.

Also note that this may return several rows if it turns out there are several students all taking the same number of courses and that number is the largest number that any student is taking.  (So, if there are 3 students taking 7 courses each, and no student taking more than 7 courses, then you will see 3 rows in the result set.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Aggregate `sc41071030` rows to get the counts.
2. Join the results to `s41071030` to:

   - filter rows on `sdept`;
   - get student details;
   - `RANK()` the joined rows on the count values.
3. Select rows with the ranking of 1.

```
WITH
  aggregated AS (
    SELECT
      sno,
      COUNT(*) AS coursecount
    FROM
      sc41071030
    GROUP BY
      sno
  ),
  ranked AS (
    SELECT
      s.*,
      RANK() OVER (ORDER BY agg.coursecount DESC) AS rnk
    FROM
      s41071030 s
      INNER JOIN aggregated agg ON s.sno = agg.sno
    WHERE
      s.sdept = 'CS'
  )
SELECT
  sno,
  sname,
  ssex,
  sage,
  sdept
FROM
  ranked
WHERE
  rnk = 1
;
```

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Re: benefit to filtering in CTE – I chose to filter in CTE because that way there would be no need to rank the entire `sc41071030` table (partitioning the rows by `sdept`) and that might be more efficient. Of course, if the `sdept` filter was in the main select, the optimiser might figure out that there was no need to apply `RANK` to all the rows but only to those matching the specified `sdept`, but I couldn't be sure. And I spared me the need to write out `PARTITION BY ...` as well. :)

Comment: Hi — back again...I was using this (and my queries) to test some new features, and ran into two problems: (1) I needed to add `ON agg.sno = s.sno` to specify the joining condition on the inner join, and (2) I needed to change `sc40171030` to `s40171030` in the `ranked` query so that `s.sdept` referred to a column.  Do you agree with those changes?  Shout if you want DDL to set up a test case (see my profile too) — the question is singularly lacking in that department.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You are absolutely right. I wrote my answer very sloppily, clearly, updating it now. Thank you very much for taking the time to let me know about those issues.